# Very scared about finding a job after Computer Science degree

Tags: software-industry

I  have just begun my final year of my Computer Science degree, I achieved a 1:1 last year. Overall I am very confident in my academic ability, however as my Degree draws to an end; the prospect of going out into the real world is hugely daunting.

I feel completely unequipped for venturing into the workplace, to work on real world dynamic projects. I feel a lot of the things I have learned on my Degree are purely academic and the little practical skills I have gained are very outdated.

I am very worried when I get a job, I will be set a task I have absolutely no Idea how to complete because I have not acquired the skills to do so.

Is this a normal feeling or am I under-estimating my own ability?

Comment: Bro, you'll be fine.  Yeah, you're going to graduate, get a job, and realize that school barely taught you anything, but that's normal.  You'll then learn a bunch, be overwhelmed, and generally be terrified.  Things will then progressively get less terrifying.  Employers hiring junior/entry-level programmers expect anyone they hire to learn a LOT on the job, and they'll help you when you have issues.

Comment: Everyone feels this way. Everyone is nervous until they get on the job for a while. Relax.

Comment: I got a first class degree in computer science. I got a first job at a blue chip company, and the first thing they said was, "Forget everything you learned on your degree. We're going to show you how to do it correctly". And they did. As long as you don't think you'll walk in knowing everything, you'll do fine.

Comment: You don't have much faith in yourself, get some

Comment: All the time you've spent working on your own projects, exploring other frameworks and languages, maybe collaborating on open-source projects, will stand you in good stead. If you haven't done any of this and just completed your coursework then you are indeed unsuited to a job.

Comment: University isn't about learning things - it's about you learning how to teach yourself things on demand - you didn't start uni knowing all you do now, and lecturers don't so much teach as just talk at you for awhile.

So you've clearly figured out how to learn something - you'll be fine.

Comment: I made a simple edit to try to get it reopened, as it already has some good answers.

Comment: Can you actually write a working program? If you can write a working program of 1000 lines or so, you will be fine. If you can't write a 20 line working program it may be difficult for you to find a position.

Comment: I think this is a great question after the edit. And yes, it's normal!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a normal feeling or am I under-estimating my own ability?

This is very normal. Even the most self-assured among us might wonder what the future holds. Leaving academia and entering the working world is a big step.

> I feel a lot of the things I have learned on my Degree are purely
>   academic and the little practical skills I have gained are very
>   outdated.

That's no different than everyone else.

College is good at giving you an overview of the domain, and helping you learn how to learn. Now as a new worker, you'll find that you have a chance to learn how things really work.

> I would love to hear the experiences, of others who have been in my
>   exact shoes. And what I should know before I start my first job in the
>   industry.

Before you start your first job, know that you will be well-served to become a life-long learner. Some think that their life is divided into three parts

1. You learn
2. You work
3. You retire

But the reality is that careers tend to be far more fluid than that. You will be in a field that is ever-changing. You have learned some, but you'll learn a lot more on the job. Then the domain will change, and you'll have to learn more. Then it will change again and you'll learn even more.

Going to college has taught you how to learn. Don't forget that - it will serve you well all through your career!

Comment: I'd go even as far as saying that, if you don't let it be debilitating, slight underestimation of ones abilities combined with drive to learn can be very potent combination. I've seen quite a lot of IT folk and "consultants" with nothing to go on but confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is a hot field right now.  Interview with enough companies and you'll surely find a job.  Even if the job isn't good, you can use that experience to look for a better job.  As long as you have work in your field, you shouldn't be too worried about finding work in the long term.

The only thing you have to worry about is answering "no" to the following questions:

1. Am I willing to move a great distance from my hometown/collegetown/preferred location to find work, even for just a year or two?
2. Am I willing to work remotely and manage myself, even for just a year or two?

If you answered yes to either of those questions: congrats!  You will probably find a job if you keep reaching out.

In the meantime, see what you can do about finding freelance work.  If not, try a side project or app to keep your skills sharp.  Showing a history of work between college or full-time jobs carries more weight than you might think.  Just don't get too discouraged from freelance/project work to keep yourself from applying, applying, applying.

Comment: Why must one need to answer "yes" to those questions. In particular #2 is not something one should answer 'yes' to being prepared for remote work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can solve problems, then that's the core skill required to excel in the business. Believing you can't because school didn't teach you how to do every task explicitly will result in you not being able to execute. Every single developer I know, including myself, is constantly referencing and researching while they work. The day you sit down and can pound out code without having to learn is the day you should realize you've gone stale and need to look for another job. /opinion

Answer (score 1):

There are chances that you felt the same before starting your degree. In the end you managed to pull it off.

Take any advice with a pinch of salt (including this), but I would like to share 3 thoughts.

1. There is a large element of chance involved when getting a job. You may end up in a great job, or in a bad job and that doesn't necessarily mean that you're great or that you're crap.
2. You will have many jobs and within each of them you will go through many phases.
3. Everybody I know in IT feels that they are lagging behind everybody else. It's a very dynamic sector.